# R language - stem completion in italian

Tags: r, stemming

I have a large corpus of text, in **italian**, to analyze using the R-language.
Almost all the preprocessing method is easily writable to adapt to my native language, with a couple of default libraries.
Problem is I can't find a way to implement a stem-completion function or method, because the default dictionaries aren't in italian. Also (mea culpa) I can't find a custom italian stem-completion dictionary.
Does anyone know how to solve this problem in any way?
Thanks a lot in advance! Have a nice day!